# Is this sentence grammatically correct? Please share your insights

Tags: grammar, semantics

Is this grammatically correct? 
"The number of potato products peaked in 2019, which is a 2% increase from 2014."

Comment: It is grammatical, but it is semantically flawed.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. That's what I thought too. How can I make it semantically correct?

Comment: In general, this sentence could be structured better. The words "which is" really do not belong because there is no previous referral. Why not try removing it or replacing it with "showing" or a similar phrase?

Answer (score 1):

"Which" in a non-restrictive relative clause can take a sentence as antecedent. In your example, taking the antecedent of "which" to be the sentence "the number of potato products peaked in 2019" makes the example grammatical.  The problem is that it is not the peaking of the number that is an increase, but rather that peak number in 2019 itself which is an increase.

So in the sense which makes it grammatical, the example sentence is slightly incoherent.